# Finding Lipschitz constant of a scalar function

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

I'm aware of how to find the Lipschitz constant of simple functions, but here I've given the function
\begin{aligned}
 f(t) = \begin{cases}
  -\frac{2}{3l}\left( 1-\frac{t}{3l}\right)~&\text{if}\quad 0\le t \le 3l,\\
 0~&\text{if}\quad 3l \le t \le 1-3l,\\
 -\frac{2}{3l}\left( 1-\frac{1-t}{3l}\right) &\text{if}\quad 1-3l \le t \le 1. 
 \end{cases}
 \end{aligned}
with $l=\frac{1}{9}$. How to find the Lipschitz constant? Do I consider the expression $$|f(t_1)-f(t_2)|\le L_f|t_1-t_2|$$ for each of the three intervals given or is there any other graphical or analytical way of finding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is differentiable in its domain D than, if its derivative is bounded in D, you have that $L_f=\sup\{|f^{'}(x)| \ : \ x \in D \}$.

The function is easily differentiable in each of the three open intervals (when you talk about derivative, you have to work on an open set because you want to do limits) but is not overall differentiable (the conjuction points are the problems).

So, for solving your problem, you can calculate the three Lipschitz constants via derivative (it's quite simple because the derivative is constant in all the three intervals) and then take as $L_f$ the maximum of these three values. Finally, you can check manually if the Lipschitz constant holds also for the boundary points (so for a generic $x$ and each of the 4 boundary points and then for every possible combination of these 4 points, which are six).

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, so $L_f = \mathrm{max} \left\{ \frac{2}{9l^2},0,-\frac{2}{9l^2}\right\}=\frac{2}{9l^2}$ right? @SilvioM

Comment: The third value is also positive since the Lipschitz constant is taken as the absolute value of the sup of the derivative. Except for this little mistake, it's correct. But this is not enough in order to conclude the exercise, you have to check if the relation $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq L_f |x-y|$ holds also for the points $y=0, 3l, 1-3l, 1$ alone with a generic $x$ and between all the possible pair of these four points, because the theorem works only where the function is differentiable and in this point the function is not.

Comment: Thanks, I think it works for the corner points as well.